# When I want to install MySQL I faced this issue "root account password" I forgot it

Tags: mysql

[This is when installation of MySQL and its request the root password but I forgot the password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQl2E.png)

Comment: I found this online but I have not tried it myself. https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/mysql/reset-mysql-root-password

Comment: Is this new installation?

Comment: Yes, but before i install MySQL

Comment: Did you remove the previous installation using the same MySQL Installer?

Answer (score 0):

Just reset your previous password using this command after login from a terminal

```
 ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';
```

for more details refer to this link https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: when i opened the documentation in step number 2: "Stop the MySQL server if it is running. For a server that is running as a Windows service, go to the Services manager: From the Start menu, select Control Panel, then Administrative Tools, then Services. Find the MySQL service in the list and stop it." i do not find the MySQL service

Answer (score 0):

I think that your data folder still exists in the same directory that you want to reinstall. I suggest the following

Copy the previous data folder to a different drive (or folder) as a backup if you still want to use it later. If you're using Windows, you'll be prompted a message to confirm data folder removal when uninstalling using the MySQL Installer:
[image]

When you see this prompt, you just open a new explorer and go to the directory then copy the data folder to another place. (Note that here my `\Program Data` folder is hidden in Windows). After you finished, just click "Yes" on the message and the installer will remove the data folder. The installer will request for a reboot after uninstalling and you can continue to reinstall afterwards.

If you didn't manage (or you don't want) to remove the previous data folder, you should encounter a "path conflict" message like this when reinstalling:
[image]

In this case, change both of the install & data directory to a different folder before you click "next".